# Hiding multiple divs within a div - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry the for noobish question, my first website.

I would like that when the ".button" div is clicked all the divs inside the ".container" div fade out or hides however it doesn't seem to be working. I would prefer to keep the js in a seperate file.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MAIN</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'> </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
            MENU
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            ^ ^ ^
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.top {
    /* Border */
    border: 5px solid gray;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    /*Positioning*/
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    /*Text*/
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    /*Border*/
    border: 10px solid gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    /*Positioning*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.button {
    /*Border*/
    border: 2px solid gray;
    background-color: black;
    width: 98%;
    /*Positioning*/
    margin-top: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*Text*/
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
}

.button:hover {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.container').hide('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('.container').find('div').hide('fast');` use this

Comment: so all the content inside of container, but just that container? also are you sure you wish to hide it all as the button is also inside of it.

Comment: Can you test with alert("some text"); to see the click  event is actually handled?

Comment: Including the clicked button?

Comment: Also you haven't included jQuery library in the page, check your browser console there will be an error. Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>` before adding your script file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the div in container to be hidden, you can use :

```
$('.container>div').hide('fast');
```

So only the div being direct child of the container will be hidden.
there would be no use to to hide a div inside an hidden div :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.container>div').hide('fast');
    });
});
```

```css
.top {
    /* Border */
    border: 5px solid gray;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    /*Positioning*/
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    /*Text*/
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    /*Border*/
    border: 10px solid gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    /*Positioning*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.button {
    /*Border*/
    border: 2px solid gray;
    background-color: black;
    width: 98%;
    /*Positioning*/
    margin-top: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*Text*/
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
}

.button:hover {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MAIN</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'> </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
            MENU
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            ^ ^ ^
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think that will solve the problem since it doesn't look like jQuery is included in the page

Comment: Amen to your comment, and glory to the snippet system to point this to the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct if you want to hide all div on `.container` div

But your problem is you didn't include the `Jquery` into your webpage

Include it on your webpage at above close tag `</body>` or at `<head>`

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
            MENU
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            ^ ^ ^
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Or

```
<head>
    <title>MAIN</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- add this -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'> </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for the helpful replies. I have gotten it working as I intended, Ill make sure to be more specific in the future.

I will now be working on adding a button tp make this reappear (which should be easy with this new knowledge).

Thanks again!